# how to configure redirect rule in Azure webapp under web.config

Tags: redirect, azure-web-app-service, web-config, http-redirect

I am trying to redirect the request which comes to **Https://www.example.ie** to **Https://www.example.com/ab-ng**. Below is the rule which I have in my web.config but not working as expected.

```
<rule name="Redirect to ab-ng" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^Https://www.example.ie$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/ab-ng/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

I am new to redirect rules, please help.

Answer (score 1):

- Change the url in `action type="Redirect"`.Remove `Https` . It has to be

```html
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/ab-ng/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

- Check whether the `web.config` file is deployed properly, It has to be under `wwwroot` directory in KUDU Console.
- In Azure portal,Make sure `HTTPS Only` is set to `On` under TLS/SSL settings.

[image]

Please refer [Web.config redirects with rewrite rules](https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-redirects-with-rewrite-rules-https-www-and-more/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20example%20above,%20the%20action%20used%20a,permanent%20or%20temporary%20redirect%20using%20the%20redirectType%20attribute.) for more information

Comment: Having Https twice was typed my mistake, i have corrected it now.